# xhtml2pdf is not displaying GBP ("£") signs while creating PDF

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation, xhtml2pdf

While creating PDF using xhtm2pdf we are unable to print "£" sign but works for dollar and euro. We have used setting font face and changed font family but still we are not able to print GBP.

Comment: Have you tried the pound sign itself? In that case, you might try the HTML entity:  **&pound;**   (don't forget the closing semicolon)

Comment: Nope, I have to apply the symbol through django filter.If i use &pound; in filter it is displaying as 123&pound;

Comment: Does the html template have a [meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp) to say the encoding is utf-8?

Comment: @Alasdair Yes even with meta tag it showing only black box.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `pisa.CreatePDF()` make sure to include encoding.

Here's what we use, obviously its a bit out of context but it was mostly copied from the example documentation.

`pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('UTF-8'), encoding="UTF-8", dest=f, link_callback=link_callback)`